# CSS selector for inline elements that are at the end of the line

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a menu with icons that are separated into groups with horizontal bars, but I want the horizontal bars to be hidden if they are at the end of a row, and I want this to work regardless of screen width. Example of what I currently have:

```css
#menu {
  background-color: #ccc;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.icon {
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.divider {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <div id="menu">
    <span class="icon"></span><span class="icon"></span><span class="icon"></span><span class="divider"></span><span class="icon"></span><span class="icon"></span><span class="icon"></span><span class="icon"></span><span class="divider"></span><span class="icon"></span><span class="icon"></span><span class="divider"></span><span class="icon"></span><span class="icon"></span><span class="icon"></span><span class="divider"></span><span class="icon"></span><span class="icon"></span>
  </div>
</html>
```

Is there any way to select bars which are the last element in the row? I would also be okay with a solution that worked in sass.

Comment: What's possible in css is the same as what's possible in sass

Comment: In a responsive design, you cannot really target the last item(without js) because you don't know when it becomes the last item. In my projects, all our responsive deign are broken down in few breakpoints, in each breakpoint range, a row always have x amount of items so it is easy to know which item to hide. You can consider this option

Answer (score 1):

If you consider a different idea to code the divider then it's possible.

Here is an example

```css
#menu {
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 390px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* resize to test */
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: horizontal;
}

.icon {
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.divider {
  position: relative;
}

.divider::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -6px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <span class="icon"></span>
  <span class="icon"></span>
  <span class="icon"></span>
  <span class="divider icon"></span>
  <span class="icon"></span>
  <span class="icon"></span>
  <span class="icon"></span>
  <span class="divider icon"></span>
  <span class="icon"></span>
  <span class="divider icon"></span>
  <span class="icon"></span>
  <span class="icon"></span>
  <span class="divider icon"></span>
  <span class="icon"></span>
</div>
```